# What Portal mod is shown in VNN's "Steam Store Major Changes" video?

Tags: portal, mod-identification

On June 14th, Valve News Network released a video discussing [Steam Direct](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1328973169870947116), Valve's game submission system that has replaced Steam Greenlight.

**The video seemed to use footage from a *Portal 1* mod, as I didn't recognise any of the levels from the original *Portal*.** I'd love to try the mod, but neither the description nor comments shed any light on the mod's name.

Here is a screenshot taken from the video:

[image: Modded Portal Level]

I've already ruled out [*Portal: Prelude*](https://www.moddb.com/mods/portal-prelude), [*Blue Portals*](https://www.moddb.com/mods/blue-portals), [*Portal Pro*](https://www.moddb.com/mods/portal-pro), [*Portal: The Flash Version Mappack*](https://portalmaps.wecreatestuff.com/), and [*Portal: Unity*](https://www.moddb.com/mods/portal-unity).

Comment: What makes you suspect a mod is even being used? The level layout? To me, it looks like normal Portal gameplay.

Comment: @TimmyJim The level layouts are different. I didn't recognise any of them from the original Portal. Turns out it was from [Aperture Dèjá vu](http://www.moddb.com/mods/aperture-dj-vu).

Comment: @TimmyJim - It doesn't look like any Portal level I've seen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Apparently the footage is from [Aperture Dèjá vu](http://www.moddb.com/mods/aperture-dj-vu); a mod for Portal 1 released in 2009.**

> [Aperture Dèjá vu] is a non-linear map which have many paths to take and reach the end. The point is, that you play a map one time and you are happy. Then you have a little break in Portal, because there aren't any new released maps for some time. But the answer is here: play the Deja-Vu again, but choose a different path with different puzzles. You can choose freely the way that is going to lead you to the end.

<sup>[*Aperture Dèjá vu's* ModDB summary](http://www.moddb.com/mods/aperture-dj-vu)</sup>

You can see the name of the mod shown on the Portal Gun itself.

[image: Mod's title circled on Portal Gun]